# How to validate dropdown field in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, validation, dropdown

I'm very new to flutter and have been trying to follow online tutorials on how to validate my fields but none of them seem to work. I'm trying to validate my dropdown field to be required. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
final _dropDownKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderFieldState>();

Widget _buildKeystageField() {
return FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
    future: placementService.fetchKeystages(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return FormBuilderDropdown<String>(
          key: _dropDownKey,
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          name: 'keystage',
          allowClear: true,
          validator: (String? value) {
            if (value != null && value.isEmpty) {
              return "Keystage cannot be empty";
            }
            return null;
          },
          hint: const Text('Please Select Keystage'),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Keystage',
            suffix: _keystageHasError
                ? const Icon(Icons.error)
                : const Icon(Icons.check),
          ),
          items: snapshot.data!.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              value: item['id'].toString(),
              child: Text(item['age_group']),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _keystageValue = value!;
              print(value);
            });
          },
        );
      } else {
        const Text('Loading...');
        const CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      return Center(
          child: Column(
        children: const [
          Text('Loading...'),
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ],
      ));
    });
```

}

Working code. Adapted from the answer provided. Changed how I create the dropdown menu and it all seems to work now. The code :

```
final _dropDownKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderFieldState>();

Widget _buildKeystageField() {
return FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
    future: placementService.fetchKeystages(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return DropdownButtonFormField(
          key: _dropDownKey,
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
          hint: const Text('Please Select Keystage'),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Keystage',
            suffix: _keystageHasError
                ? const Icon(Icons.error)
                : const Icon(Icons.check),
          ),
          items: snapshot.data!.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              value: item['id'].toString(),
              child: Text(item['age_group']),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (String? value) {
            setState(() {
              _keystageValue = value!;
              print(value);
            });
          },
          validator: (String? value) {
            return value == null ? "Choose item from list" : null;
          },
        );
      } else {
        const Text('Loading...');
        const CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      return Center(
          child: Column(
        children: const [
          Text('Loading...'),
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ],
      ));
    });
```

}

Comment: Which package are u using?

Comment: import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart'; for the form
import 'package:form_builder_validators/form_builder_validators.dart'; for the validation

Comment: Did you create dropdownKey? - final _dropDownKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderFieldState>();

Comment: no. Where would I add that?

Comment: I've edited the post. But it's still not displaying the error message.

Comment: final _dropDownKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderFieldState>();
            
//Reference the key
FormBuilderDropdown(key:_dropDownKey) Can you do like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a minimal code for validating the drop-down list. (Without using any 3rd party packages.)

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<String> list = <String>[
    "heads",
    "tails",
  ];

  String? dropDownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                value: dropDownValue,
                items: list.map(
                  (String label) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: label,
                      child: Text(
                        label,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
                hint: const Text("Choose"),
                onChanged: (String? value) {
                  dropDownValue = value;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                validator: (String? value) {
                  return value == null ? "Choose item from list" : null;
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                    // validation passed
                  } else {
                    // validation failed
                  }
                },
                child: const Text("Submit"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @JacPhillipps I'm glad you liked it. Thank you so much for the upvote and for accepting my answer.